# Jquery: Truncate element content using .substring

Tags: jquery, substring, truncate

I'm trying to use jQuery to take the content of an element, truncate it by character length, then display the output in a new element. I've looked at a number of similar forum posts but can't get anything to work! What am I doing wrong here? (this is one of many attempts)

```
$('dd.event_time').each(function(){
    var time = $(this).text(); //Get text content from element
    var timeTrim = time.substring(0, 6);  //Truncate content after 6th character

    $(this).parent().append('<dd class="event-time-header">' + timeTrim + '</dd>'); //Wrap output in new element
});
```

Getting the element content works, so does the final step. It's just the `.substring` part I'm having problems with.
I'm fairly new to jQuery by the way.

Comment: What are you trying to truncate leading and trailing whitespace?

Comment: The substring function looks correct, as long as the time is 5 or more characters long. Is it? Are you sure it is grabbing the text from the element?

Comment: The date format is currently being display as a start time and end time e.g. 5:50pm - 8:20pm. I want to get rid of the end date. I figured I could limit the character length to do this. Unless there's a better method? Maybe I could tell it to only display the first word somehow?

Answer (score 1):

That's the difference between `substr` and `substring`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

> string.substr(start[, length])

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring

> string.substring(indexA[, indexB])

Comment: I've tried using subtr and substring in the code I originally posted. Doesn't seem to be working either way for me.

Comment: @user1469087 what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Can you tell us what you obtain and what you expect?

Comment: Ok I've discovered there must be something within the content management system I am using that is over-riding my Jquery. I have tested it on a locally hosted file and it's working fine there.